# 100 days in BETA - discussion, thoughts, improvements...?

Tags: discussion

Just saw this site is 100 days in BETA

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage

Maybe a good opportunity to gather some subjective ideas, improvements, critics to consider in future site development/growth and moderation/editing of Q/A? Just a bit brainstorming :)

Comment: Follow-up: [When will our site graduate from beta?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/347/1859)

Answer (score 4):

one thing i noticed on my last question is that question-edit-duplicate-preview doesnt obviously show german duplicates if you ask a english question. I think this is a bit suboptimal and should be improved. Also because of search results on google. On japanese language questions seem to be mainly written in english.

I think we should also attract native-germans not fluently speaking english, but maybe there is a option to give a german question title in META-information of html-code or as smaller written subtext below the english question title? Im no expert here! Just an idea...

Comment: If you think so - maybe you should translate this statement into German. ;) -- Wenn Du das meinst, übersetze Deinen Beitrag doch ins Deutsche. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Visiting japanese language

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language-usage

im a bit surprised that they seem to have more questions&visits/day despite lower user number? Im not very experienced with AREA51 and exact definition of this quantities. But do they have a higher community dynamics? Maybe not significant, but looks a bit weird to me comparing the numbers...