# When will our site graduate from beta?

Tags: discussion, support

[This question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/100-days-in-beta-discussion-thoughts-improvements) didn't get much attention, even though at that time GLU was 100 days in beta phase. But now, it's **262 days**.

Many old users lost their interest and left. If I wasn't highly motivated to keep learning German, I'd leave the site many years ago!

Is there anything we can do about it before it turns to a ghost town?

Maybe we need something like [what they're doing on Chinese Language and Usage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1984/chinese-language-and-usage?tab=schedule) or [what they did on parenting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers) or according to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/):

> [...] But if you want your site to graduate from beta sooner rather than later, encourage your fellow community members [to vote early and often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)!

Answer (score 4):

Actually... I've seen worse! :)  According to the stats, we're doing well except for two cases:

1. Questions per day
2. Visits

You can "easily" increase them both by doing some things. For example:

1. Share. Wherever you think people would like to see a link to German-related stuff. Use the buttons, paste the link, however is fine but just share. :D
2. If you know someone who might be interested but couldn't see the link, tell them by talking.

You can also edit the posts, adjust the formatting, vote to close the bad questions, this will improve the quality and people will notice this, trust me. They'll come back.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (2014/07/26) we're `Excellent` in the department of visits/day. It's 5164 visits/day which is 3 times more than the 1500 visits/day limit for qualifying as `Good`.

The real worry is the number of questions per day. It's at 4.3 questions/day — in this case less than a third of the 15 questions/day limit for qualifying as `Good`.

So what we need to survive is more questions and more really good quality questions. Quality questions are important because they generate a lot of discussion and are the seeds for great answers.

Comment: There is more than the statistics on Area51 needed for graduation. One issue sadly still is obvious: overall community activities in chat and Meta are rather low.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of surprised by the low chat activity. My guess is that on german.SE there're really good German speakers or complete newbies like me.

Comment: @Takkat definitely.. when checking the stats for [codereview.se], you can see, that the area51 metrics are often at least double of the acceptance criteria, but still there is problems with meta participation and user retention and that's why no graduation is scheduled as of now..

Comment: I do not think that a high chat activity is required for graduation (which does not mean that it does not help), *Academia* has a rather inactive chat, too. On another note, [with *Japanese,* the first non-English language SE is about to graduate](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1155) and [their Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526) are not that different from [ours](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413).